# Python: How to dynamically write to multiple files

Tags: python

I am sequentially logging data packets from multiple streams.
Depending on the data in each packet, I need to write the data to a specific log file.
I will have up to 8 files open at a time to cater for a maximum 8 concurrent data streams
The log files are opened and closed at the start and finish of a new data stream.

I have come up with the following code to handle the write operations.

```
#Identify where the data needs to be stored
filePointer = unpack_from('!B',payload, 4)

#Grab the data          
capData = unpack_from('!160s', payload, 10)         

#Store the data
if filePointer[0] == 1: Logfile1.write(str(capData[0]))
elif filePointer[0] == 2: Logfile2.write(str(capData[0]))
elif filePointer[0] == 3: Logfile3.write(str(capData[0]))
elif filePointer[0] == 4: Logfile4.write(str(capData[0]))
elif filePointer[0] == 5: Logfile5.write(str(capData[0]))
elif filePointer[0] == 6: Logfile6.write(str(capData[0]))
elif filePointer[0] == 7: Logfile7.write(str(capData[0]))
elif filePointer[0] == 8: Logfile8.write(str(capData[0]))
```

Is there a nicer more pythony way to do this?

Can a variable be somehow used to make up the file handle or return the required file handle?

Cheers

Pob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build a dictionary of filepointers and use it to dynamically select the file:

```
d = {1: Logfile1, 2: Logfile2, ...}
curr_file = d[filePointer[0]]
curr_file.write(str(capData[0]))
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I'll give this a go.  Can this technique be used to open the files as well?

Comment: Sure, you can try something like d = {i+1: open(f) for i, f in zip(range(len(file_list)), file_list)}. This gives you the file handlers directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a list, say "logfiles", to store your "logfileN" file objects.

Or a dict, code example:

```
logfiles = {}
for i in range(1, 9):
    logfiles[i] = open("Mylog_%s.log"%(i,), "w")


for filePointer, capData in yourLoop: 
    logfiles[filePointer[0]].write(str(capData[0]))
```

(add error control as you like)

Comment: Thanks, I think this answers my question for Daniel about handling the file opens as well.  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

use dict, map filePointer[0] to logfile

Answer (score 1):

I think the pythonic way is something like this:

```
logFileHandlers = {
    1: Logfile1,
    2: Logfile2,
    3: Logfile3,
    4: Logfile4,
    5: Logfile5,
    6: Logfile6,
    7: Logfile7,
    8: Logfile8,
}
try:
    fileHandler = logFileHandlers[filePointer[0]]
    fileHandler.write(str(capData[0]))
except KeyError as e:
    print e # handle exception: unrecognized data from stream
```